# Solving $ \lim_{x^2+y^2 \to +\infty}\frac{\log{\left(x^2+e^{|x|+|y|}\right)}}{x^2y^2+|x|+|y|} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm pretty sure that limit tends to zero in $\Bbb D=[1, +\infty[ \times [1, +\infty[$
$$
\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to +\infty}\frac{\log{\left(x^2+e^{|x|+|y|}\right)}}{x^2y^2+|x|+|y|}
$$
But every estimation I did ended up with $f(x,y) \le g(x,y)$ with $g(x,y) \to 1$ (if anybody wants to see, I'll edit the post with my attempts).
Has anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea:
$$
\log(x^2+e^{|x|+|y|})=|x|+|y|+\log(1+x^2e^{-|x|-|y|}).
$$
Now prove that
$$
(x,y)\mapsto x^2e^{-|x|-|y|}
$$
is bounded on $\mathbb{D}$.

Then, to estimate $|x|+|y|=x+y$ by $x^2y^2$, note that as $x,y\geq 1$ we have
$$
0\leq (x-1)(y-1)\implies x+y\leq 1+xy\leq 2xy.
$$

Comment: I've already tried this path, but anyway the estimation that make me trouble is: $\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2y^2+|x|+|y|}$. The only thing come into my mind is something like: $|x|+|y| \le x^2y^2$ or $|x|+|y| = |u|$ and $|x||y| = |v|$

Comment: @DOmonoXYLEDyL I edited my answer, hopefully it helps you now :)

Comment: thanks a lot for your great help!! :D